# Mobiscroll scroller - set default value

Tags: jquery, mobiscroll

I am very new to mobiscroll and trying to set the default value for mobiscroll scroller.

Here is my code:

```
<input type='hidden' id='test'/>
```

```
$('#test').scroller({
    theme: 'sense-ui',
    display: 'inline',
    mode: 'mixed',
    wheels: wheel,
    defaultValue:'10',
    showLabel: false,
    showInput: false
});
```

Can anyone help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#test').scroller({
theme: 'sense-ui',
display: 'inline',
mode: 'mixed',
wheels: wheel,
defaultValue:'10',
showLabel: false,
showInput: false
}).scroller('setValue', 'YOUR VALUE', true);
```